# algorithm to compare two lists and get same elements in python

Tags: python

I have to lists, which has some common elements in them:

```
p = [('link1/d/b/c', 'target1/d/b/c'), ('link2/a/g/c', 'target2/a/g/c'), ..., ('linkn/b/b/f', 'targetn/b/b/f')]

q = [['target1/d/b/c', 'target1', 123, 334], ['targetn/b/b/f', 'targetn', 23, 64], ... ,['targetx/f/f/f', 'targetx', 999, 888]]
```

Im trying to compare them and find common elements, and then do some job with result:

```
do_job('target1/d/b/c', 'target1', 123, 334, 'link1/d/b/c')
```

for now im using simple and very slow alghortihm:

```
for item in p:
   link = item[0]
   target = item[1]
   for item2 in q:
       target2 = item2[0]
       if target2 == target:
           do_some_job(...)
```

I thougth, that I need to compare this two lists and get create one list which will contain all elements, eg:

```
pq = [['target1/d/b/c', 'target1', 123, 334, 'link1/d/b/c'], ..., ['targetn/b/b/f', 'targetn', 23, 64, 'linkn/b/b/f']]
```

and then call `do_some_job(pq)` instead of calling it each time when I found  same element

How to gain it ?

best regards

Comment: That are no Python lists. What is `link1/d/b/c` supposed to mean?

Comment: use quotes for strings like `'target1/d/b/c'`.

Answer (score 5):

use `chain()` to flatten the two lists, and then use `set()` and `intersection()` to get the common elements.

```
In [78]: from itertools import chain

In [79]: p
Out[79]: 
[('link1/d/b/c', 'target1/d/b/c'),
 ('link2/a/g/c', 'target2/a/g/c'),
 ('linkn/b/b/f', 'targetn/b/b/f')]

In [80]: q
Out[80]: 
[['target1/d/b/c', 'target1', 123, 334],
 ['targetn/b/b/f', 'targetn', 23, 64],
 ['targetx/f/f/f', 'targetx', 999, 888]]

In [81]: set(chain(*p)).intersection(set(chain(*q)))
Out[81]: set(['target1/d/b/c', 'targetn/b/b/f'])
```

or use a list comprehension with short-circuiting :

```
In [86]: [j for i in p for j in i if j in (z for y in q for z in y)]
Out[86]: ['target1/d/b/c', 'targetn/b/b/f']
```

or using `any()`:

```
In [87]: [j for i in p for j in i if any (j==z for y in q for z in y)]
Out[87]: ['target1/d/b/c', 'targetn/b/b/f']
```

**timeit**:

```
In [93]: %timeit set(chain(*p)).intersection(set(chain(*q)))
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.38 us per loop                     ##  winner

In [94]: %timeit [j for i in p for j in i if j in (z for y in q for z in y)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 24.9 us per loop

In [95]: %timeit [j for i in p for j in i if any (j==z for y in q for z in y)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 27.4 us per loop

In [97]: %timeit [x for x in chain(*p) if x in chain(*q)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 12.6 us per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use a dictionary:

```
target_to_link = dict((v,k) for (k,v) in p)
for item in q:
    args = item + [target_to_link[item[0]]
    do_some_job(*args)
```

The `target_to_link` dictionary gives you the corresponding link from your target. Just make sure that you don't have several targets sharing the same link...

In the `for` loop, we just create a temporary list of arguments `args` that combine your `item` (eg, `['target1/d/b/c', 'target1', 123, 334]`) with the corresponding link and we use the `function(*args)` syntax...

---

If you need to be looping on `p` instead, you can construct a dictionary like

```
target_to_args = dict((k[0],k[1:]) for k in q)
```

then do something like

```
for (link, target) in p:
    args = [target] + target_to_args[target] + [link]
    do_some_job(*args)
```

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension with `chain` should work:

```
[x for x in chain(*p) if x in chain(*q)]
```

Comment: If you are referring to itertools.chain, it returns an iterable therefore not sure that "in" would work? In any case the set-based approach from ashwini's solution is likely to be faster

Comment: @cravoori `in` works fine with iterable, it is similar to `any()` and does short-circuiting. see http://pastebin.com/scfnXTyY

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, it works in this example because every time "if x in chain" is evaluated a new iterator is created, which is obviously expensive. An iterator is exhausted after a single pass which implies iterators are not suitable for containment checks. Here is an example, http://pastebin.com/209fFHUn